# Intento almacenar en el json_encode una imagen de la base de datos pero no lo toma, he intentado convertir la imagen con base 64 pero no me funciona

Tags: javascript, php, json, phpmyadmin

**aqui tomo los datos de mi tabla troquel de la base de datos y lo recorro con un while y realizo un arreglo de los campos con mysqli_fetch_assoc**

```
 while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultar))$data['Img_troquel']);

                                $detalleTabla .= '
                                <tr class="item">
                                    <td class="item__items"><a href="#" onclick="selectTroquel('.$data['Id_troquel'].');recargar(event);" class="select--troquel"><img src="src/svg/select.svg" alt="Seleccionar" class="svg svg--select"></a></td>
                                    <td class="item__items">'.$data['Nombre_troquel'].'</td>
                                    <td class="item__items">'.$data['DCM'].'</td>
                                    <td class="item__items"><img src="" alt="Imagen troquel" class="img__troquel"></td>  /* aqui va la imagen de la base de datos */
                                </tr>
                                ';                }
                            $detalleTabla .= '
                            </table>
                            ';
               $arrayData['detalle'] = $detalleTabla;
```

> aqui uso el json_encode para luego recibirlo en javascript y pasar los datos a un contenendor div

```
echo json_encode($arrayData,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            } else {
                echo 'error';
            }
            mysqli_close($conex);  
        exit;
```

> este es el javascript con el jquery

```
$("#buscar--troquel").click(function (e) {  
        var action = "buscarTroquel";
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax.php",
          async: true,
          data: { action: action },
          success: function (response) {
            if (response != "error") {
              console.log(response);
              var infoTroquel= JSON.parse(response);
                  $("#modal__troquel").html(infoTroquel.detalle);
            } else {
              console.log("no data");
            }
          },
          error: function (error) {},
  });
        });
```

Comment: `"data:" . $img_mime_type . ";base64, " . base64_encode( $img_binary_data )`

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero como incluyo esto en el array

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví tomando el binario y convirtiéndolo en base 64.

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta. Además, en lo posible, provee más detalles. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta. Lee [answer].